# How do I make a proper event listener for a JTextField that can identify the source?

Tags: java, swing, listener

I need the listener to fire whenever the user clicks onto a different component, not just when the enter key is pressed. I also need to identify the source because I have hundreds of JTextField's and the only way I have to identify them is through an array index.

I can get the source from an ActionListener, but an ActionListener only fires when the user presses the enter key.

I can attach a DocumentListener to the associated Document of the JTextField, but there doesn't seem to be a way to get a reference to the JTextField itself.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Oracle explanation for [How to Write a Document Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html), it appears you can put one or more properties on a Document.

Here's two lines of code from the explanation.

```
textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new MyDocumentListener());
textField.getDocument().putProperty("name", "Text Field");
```

Well, you can change the second line to something like this:

```
textField.getDocument().putProperty("index", Integer.toString(index));
```

Later in the Document Listener code, you'd use this method to get the property.

```
document.getProperty("index");
```

Comment: Thanks that appears to exactly answer my question. I'll have to consider using a JTable as next answer suggests also.

Answer (score 1):

> I have hundreds of JTextField's and the only way I have to identify
>   them is through an array index.

use [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) instead of hundreds of [`JTextField's`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)

> I can get the source from an ActionListener, but an ActionListener
>   only fires when the user presses the enter key.

[`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) is fired only if `ENTER key` is pressed, and for [`JTextField`, `JFormattedTextField` and `JPasswordField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)

> can attach a DocumentListener to the associated Document of the
>   JTextField, but there doesn't seem to be a way to get a reference to
>   the JTextField itself.

from each of [`Listeners`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/eventsandcomponents.html) you can to identify which from [`JComponents`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) firing this event